# Correct/fix "gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file" in .gz file?

Tags: shell-script, gzip

I use `adb backup` to backup my Android smartphone; and as noted in many posts, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533567/how-to-extract-or-unpack-an-ab-file-android-backup-file - I have tried to convert it to .gz; for instance:

```bsh
$ adb backup -apk -shared -all -f mybackup.ab
Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation...

$ (printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" ; tail -n +5 mybackup.ab) > mybackup.gz

$ tar tzvf mybackup.gz
...
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
drwxrwx--- 0/9997             0 2020-02-22 10:23 shared/0/Notifications
drwxrwx--- 0/9997             0 2020-02-22 10:23 shared/0/Ringtones
drwxrwx--- 0/9997             0 2020-02-22 10:23 shared/0/Podcasts
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

A comment in the linked SO post mentions:

> It is probably complaining because the backup.ab doesn't have the proper gzip file footer with CRC-32 checksum and length

So, my question is: given a mybackup.gz like above, which has a correct .gz file header but incorrect file footer - how could I generate and append or replace the footer (hopefully this is doable in plain shell/Bash, but I wouldn't mind a different language solution), so that from `mybackup.gz` I obtain `mybackup_fixed.gz`, which would contain all available data, but would not cause a `unexpected end of file` when inspected with, say, `tar tzvf`?

Comment: That magic command doesn't not look the same as in the answer to the SO question. Your `tail` command is quite different from `tail -c +25 mybackup.ab`.